# The best method to add new values only from destination to source

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables. table1 (source) and table2 (destination). I want to whole records in table2 to be copied to table1 if and only if the record is not already exists in table1. I use the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO test.dest
SELECT * 
FROM test.source
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM test.dest
                 WHERE (source.DomainName=dest.hostnmae)
                 );
```

My question: Is there another better method to speed the process??

Comment: Do you have an index on dest.hostname?

Comment: I didn't explicitly specified an index key during table creation. However, I mostly create and edit tables using the GUI of MySQL workbench. Does `order by` statement does the purpose of index? Or shall I specify index key ??

Comment: Specify an index key directly.  This should improve performance for your query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Do I need to specify index in both tables?

Comment: My guess is that the biggest improvement would be an index on the dest table.  There would probably be some, but smaller, improvement for an index on the test table.